# Automate cell properties multiple Excel files

Tags: excel

I have about 100 Excel files, in which columns K and L are represented as floating points, for instance 0.5677. I want to represent those columns as percentages, in this case 56.8%. Is there a way I can automate this? Obviously I can adjust the columns by hand, but this is quite time consuming.

I have no experience with Macro's or VBA.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards, M.

Answer (score 0):

I found a useful way to do this using Python Pandas. In my case, Pandas is also the source for the Excel files.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Numbers':    [1010, 2020, 3030, 2020, 1515, 3030, 4545],
                   'Percentage': [.1,   .2,   .33,  .25,  .5,   .75,  .45 ],
})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("pandas_column_formats.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Add some cell formats.
format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00'})
format2 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0%'})

# Note: It isn't possible to format any cells that already have a format such
# as the index or headers or any cells that contain dates or datetimes.

# Set the column width and format.
worksheet.set_column('B:B', 18, format1)

# Set the format but not the column width.
worksheet.set_column('C:C', None, format2)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```